# Nodejs express bodyParser drops object keys

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, server, body-parser

I'm using nodejs express 4.16.3 with body-parser 1.18.3

I'm sending JSON object by ajax from front to my server to save it as .json file.

There is my front code:

```
function sendobj (datapack) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(datapack))
  $.ajax({
    url: '/save',
    method: "POST",
    data: datapack,
    success: function(results) {
      alert(results.status)
    }
  });
}
```

and console output after triggering this function & ajax call

```
{"nametest":{
"lov":{"2":{"val":"15"}},
"gte":{"2":{"val":"9"}},
}}
```

At this point, everything is OK - "lov" and "gte" are objects, both with key "2" as I need.

But on server side, there is my app code:

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.post('/save', async (req, res) => {
      try {
      console.log(req.body)

      await fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(req.body), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        status: 'Error!'
      })
      return
    }

    res.send({
      status: 'Saved!'
    })

  });

} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
});
```

Server console output:

```
{ nametest:
{ gte: [ { val: '9' } ],
  lov: [ { val: '15' } ]
   } }
```

output.json

```
{"nametest":{"gte":[{"val":"9"}],"lov":[{"val":"15"}]}}
```

It looks like my primary objects 'gte' and 'lov' gets converted into arrays and they lost them keys..

Am I missing something in my app/ajax setup ?

Comment: This probably doesn't relate to your problem, but async/await only works with Promises, and fs.writeFile does not return a Promise.

Comment: Your console.log is only a superficial view if the file has received the correct data, then the body data is correct, if you still have questions, use Object.keys () in your object and see the keys. And as paul said, await will only get results if there is a promise fs.writeFile is not a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AJAX request, you need to stringify your payload.

```
function sendobj (datapack) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(datapack))
  $.ajax({
  url: '/save',
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(datapack),
  success: function(results) {
    alert(results.status)
  }
  });
}
```

In express, make sure to add `application/json` type. As in

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
```

Then log out nametest. `req.body.nametest`
This is the output I got

```
{ lov: { '2': { val: '15' } }, gte: { '2': { val: '9' } } }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: console.log(req.body.nametest) giving me undefined in server console
and at server side data looks this: { '{"nametest":{"lov":{"2":{"val":"17"}},"gte":{"2":{"val":"9"}} }

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are not sending over valid JSON?

Try this. You have an extra comma.

```
{"nametest":{
"lov":{"2":{"val":"15"}},
"gte":{"2":{"val":"9"}}
}}
```

Comment: This comma was a typo, if it existed the middleware had returned a json syntax error.